# How to correctly configure SAML 2.0 SP in OWIN flow

Tags: owin, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

I am trying to use SAML using Kentor auth services in my OWIN web site. But there is something wrong with the configuration i think, as SAML return Url is not same as what i configured. There must something wrong i am doing.

Here is the configuration

```
<kentor.authServices entityId="https://admin.mercedes-forms.ggg.com.au" returnUrl="http://admin.mercedes-forms.ggg.com.au/Callback/Saml2">    
    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://int.smfed.extranet.daimler.com/" 
           signOnUrl="https://cdiwl-appstest.i.daimler.com/affwebservices/public/saml2sso" 
           allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
        <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/int.smfed.extranet.daimler.com.cer" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
    <federations>
      <add metadataLocation="http://admin.mercedes-forms.ggg.com.au/Federation" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" />
    </federations>
    <serviceCertificates>
      <add fileName="~/App_Data/Kentor.AuthServices.StubIdp.cer" />
    </serviceCertificates>
  </kentor.authServices>
```

Here is the authentication request

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="idaa4b00c6cd334f5c927526106a6da12f" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-04-05T00:18:45Z" Destination="https://cdiwl-appstest.i.daimler.com/affwebservices/public/saml2sso" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://admin.mercedes-forms.ggg.com.au/AuthServices/Acs">
  <saml2:Issuer>https://admin.mercedes-forms.ggg.com.au</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need both the IdentityProvider entry and the federations entry? Seems you would want one or the other but not both.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, the IdentityProvider entry should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

`ReturnUrl` is used **after** the SAML is processed by AuthServices in your application. So it is correct that your `ReturnUrl` value is not reflected in the `AssertionConsumerServiceURL` you see in the authentication request. If you want to customize the location of that, the `ModulePath` parameter is more what you are looking for: https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/doc/Configuration.md#modulepath-attribute

For example, the typical flow might be something like this:

1. Use requests /somesecurepath in your application
2. Your authentication sytem, involving AuthServices, redirects them to the identity provider, saving the value of /somesecurepath for step 4
3. The identity provider posts the SAML back to the Assertion Consumer Service located at /AuthServices/Acs (unless you have customized this location with ModulePath option)
4. AuthServices redirects to the original requested location from step 1

The `ReturnUrl` value only comes into play if there is no original requested location saved, e.g. for an unsolicited/idp-initiated flow.